# how to install mssql module on centos server 6.7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cpanel, centos6, yum

How to install mssql client module on centos server 6.7. I am trying to install the mssql client and going through the process described in this article 
http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/37/comment-page-1#comment-188819

but I am stuck on "yum install php-devel" . It does not find the package.

I followed another post regarding the same topic where it is mentioned that you have to remove php* from yum.conf exclude but also mentioned that it might cause problem if you have WHM/Cpanel.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82478/cannot-install-php-packages-in-centos

I have WHM/Cpanel on my server and i am trying to figure out how to proceed with installing mssql

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the following command.

```
wget http://ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/stable/freetds-stable.tgz
tar zfvx freetds-stable.tgz
cd freetds-*;
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --with-tdsver=8.0 --enable-msdblib --enable-dbmfix --with-gnu-ld; make ; make install
```

Add the compile flag for freetds to /var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5

```
echo "--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds" >> /var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5

touch /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtds.a
touch /usr/local/freetds/include/tds.hp
```

Now run Easy Apache

```
/scripts/easyapache
```

Comment: will this cause problem with the existing WHM/Cpanel and the websites that are residing in the server ?